# GET returns https:/ not https://

Tags: php, url, get

I am trying to parse a url from `$_GET['url']` using https://github.com/spatie/url but the GET returns a not valid url, so to speak.

`https://duckduckgo.com` in `http://localhost/blog/external-link/https://duckduckgo.com` returns `https:/duckduckgo.com` when I use `echo $_GET['url'];`.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: be careful with an approach like this ( when it is working ) - unless the target urls are in your database or whitelisted then it is easy to use your site to launch urls to random domains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to urlencode the URL-Part:

```
echo urlencode('https://duckduckgo.com');
```

this will return `https%3A%2F%2Fduckduckgo.com`

Thats because the `/`-Sign has a special meaning in urls. You cannot use it unencoded.
So try `http://localhost/blog/external-link/https%3A%2F%2Fduckduckgo.com` and you will be more successfull.

Comment: Thank you. `http://localhost/blog/external-link/https%3A%2F%2Fduckduckgo.com` returns "Object not found" on my web server though, but now I have more flesh on my bones.